# Starting an executable Task vs Process in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, scheduled-tasks

I am building a client-side utility program(Application Upgrader) in C# which periodically checks with the server if the upgrade is available and downloads it if it is so else it does nothing. Currently, I have two approaches in mind - Process-based and Task-based. In both approaches, I am starting the Upgrader from the Main method (of console application). Which of these two approaches should be used?
provided the requirements -

- the Upgrader utility should run asynchronously (without blocking the Main)
- and once the upgrade is downloaded, it should prompt the user to install it right away or later

Secondly, how to schedule the periodic execution of "upgrader.exe" from the Main() in the code below?
Also, is there a better way to achieve this functionality of asynchronous download? I envision a sort of upgrades that we see happening on mobile apps in the background and then a prompt is there asking for installation.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = @"C:\Users\abc\upgrader.exe";
        Console.WriteLine(FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Hello World"));
        Console.WriteLine("About to start the upgrader process now...");

        // Approch 1: DirectlyProcess based
        //using(Process myprocess = new Process())
        //{
        //    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
        //    myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //    myprocess.Start();
        //}

        // Approach 2: Task based
        await RunProcessAsync(filename).ContinueWith(taskres => Console.WriteLine($"taskresult is: {taskres}"));
        Console.WriteLine("This code runs after RunProcessAsyncFinishes. Pop up a windows to ask install now or later");
    }

    static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string filename)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        var upgraderprocess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = filename
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        upgraderprocess.Exited += (sender, args) =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(upgraderprocess.ExitCode);
            upgraderprocess.Dispose();
        };

        upgraderprocess.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided for your second question implies that you have already decided about your first question: you favor a process-based approach over a task-based approach. I deduce this by the two approaches you display in your code sample, which are 1) start a process and forget it or 2) start a process and have a way to await it. So there are a couple of approaches-pairs here. A) process-based vs task-based dilemma and B) a process-fire-and-forget vs process-awaitable dilemma. All this is quite confusing, and this is why it is recommended to ask a single question in every "Question".

Comment: @TheodorZoulias To clear the confusion, I am more interested in a mix of A) process-fire-and-forget and B) process-awaitable , because A provides me the option of running Upgrader.exe separately from the caller without having to worry about Caller process dying/getting killed and B provides me the option to perform some task once Upgrader.exe has finished execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your first question,** while tasks share the same memory space and should run under another process, processes have their own memory space and they can run independently from any other process. This feature has ups and downs. The good thing is you can run a process and kill the main process which runs it at the first place, the second process will still be alive. But the bad thing is if you need to share some properties or memory space with another process, it may require some workarounds.

**For your second question,** you may think to use **Scheduled Tasks** for Windows Server. Or you can register this functionality **as a Service** (easiest way to do it is using **TopShelf, https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf**) and set a timer  in it to create some interval for execution.

Just look these 2 options and select best one which suits with your requirements. For any other questions, drop me a line in comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess starting a process would be a good choice for me here, as the first process who started the upgrader.exe can be killed/die, but can I schedule the Upgrader.exe from the Caller Process itself? As far as showing the prompt for installation is concerned, that would need to be handled in the Upgrader.exe itself in case of "Process approach" but would need to handle in the Caller process itself if implemented using the "Task approach". Is that correct?

Comment: This might be an answer for your following questions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6920e038-fbb7-4f14-9068-e7112ea20cca/how-to-create-new-scheduled-task-programmatically?forum=csharpgeneral